# Coving around borrowed light doorframe

Tags: bedroom

Have a 70s build house with covered borrowed light above the doorframe. How would one go about fitting coving in this case to achieve a quality finish? I can either (1) attempt to route the coving to the frame shape, (2) terminate the coving at the doorframe, or (3) attempt to somehow remove the borrowed light gap and skim. Option 3 might achieve best finish, but I am unsure how to go about the task. Am I missing any options?

[image]

Comment: Location? Not that it matters; I just haven't heard the term "borrowed light" before and I'm wondering where it's in use. I'd have called that a transom.

Comment: Would you prefer to remove the transom? It's fairly trivial if you're comfortable working with sheetrock.